# VB.net Excel styling

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, excel, excel-2007

Hey all i am trying to add some style properties to a column but the code i am currently using doesnt seem to work at all?

```
    Dim oApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook = oApp.Workbooks.Add()
    Dim oWS As Excel.Worksheet = CType(oWB.Worksheets(1), Excel.Worksheet)
    Dim style As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Style

    style = oWB.Styles.Add("Style1")
    style.NumberFormat = "Text"
    style.Font.Name = "Arial"
    style.Font.Bold = True
    style.Font.Size = 5
    style.Interior.Pattern = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPattern.xlPatternSolid

    oWS.Cells(1, 1) = "repairinv PROG"
    oWS.Cells(1, 2) = "repairinv TEST"
```

It's still the same as "default" would look when just opening up excel for the first time.

Any help would be great! :o)

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the style of the `.Cell` range to the style you want. E.g.:

```
oWS.Cells(1, 1).Style = "Style1"
oWS.Cells(1, 2).Style = "Style1"
```